# pods in a framework, import that framework for main project in swift

Tags: swift, api, frameworks, cocoapods

The idea is to have an api framework (new project -> cocoa touch framework) for example "SuperApi". SuperApi use pods like Alamofire, ObjectMapper and whatever I need.

Next I want to integrate that SuperApi into my app like a normal framework.

I tried different ways. I tried to add it at "Embedded Binaries" and/or tried to add superApi at "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". Without success. I always linked the whole framework-folder.

`import SuperApi` threw always an error: could not find framework

Then I read something about workspaces where I can have a lot of projects parallel. This seems really overpowered for an api.

Create a framework without pods (xcodeproj) is no problem. There are a lot of descriptions in web. But what is a (good) solution for my problem? 
I don't want to write my own http-networking + JSON parser. Thanks for input.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add your SuperApi as a pod of your main project? You can have it either as a local pod, directly linking [the last commit](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#plugin) or using your own [private repo](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html)

There's a very nice tutorial by Ray Wenderlich: https://www.raywenderlich.com/99386/create-cocoapod-swift

Comment: thanks for that. Did you try already? Is it possible to  integrate pods into a pod? Edit: Stupid comment from me: Yes it is possible, I should look first to link content.

Comment: Yep! I have a 3 layer architecture and domain and data layers are private pods ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eli. I found this video, it's more up to date
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNMNeqXKnzw&t=964s (thanks to you Mr. Levi Bostian - you made my day)

Unfortunately this video is a litte bit outdated too.

You run into a Swift 2/3 issue. So you have to create a `.swift-version` in your git. For example Alamofire did it like this: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/.swift-version

You can do it like this in your pod-folder: `echo 3.0 > .swift-version`

I ran into a second issue, because my pod wasn't up to date. So update your pod `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`

Last but not least I had a warning in my podspec, so I have to use `pod spec lint --allow warnings`

Better way is to fix the warning ;)